# Формирование xml из базы данных с#

Tags: c#, xml, sqlce

пытаюсь сформировать xml из базы данных, это вид который должен быть

```
<status count="1">
      <payment trn="1000000011" />
      <payment trn="1000000011" />
      <payment trn="1000000011" />
      <payment trn="1000000011" />
      <payment trn="1000000011" />
      <payment trn="1000000011" />
      </status>
    </request>
```

но не получается записать все данные из базы в xml вот код

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "payment")]
        public class Payment2
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "trn")]
            public string Trn { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "status")]
        public class Status
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "payment")]
            public List<Payment> Payment { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "count")]
            public string Count { get; set; }
        }


string DBlink = String.Format("{0}\\Database.sdf", Application.StartupPath);
string conString = @"Data Source=" + DBlink;
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
con.Open();
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT id_trn FROM [payments] WHERE result_code=215", con);
using (SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
{
 while (reader.Read())
                    {   
Status = new Status();
Status.Count = "1";
Status.Payment = new List<Payment>();
for (int i = 0; reader.FieldCount > i; i++)
{
Status.Payment.Add(new Payment {Trn=reader[0].ToString()});}
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"get_status.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
formatter.Serialize(fs, Status);
}
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Ошибку какую то выдает, неправильно XML формирует или еще чего?

Comment: Почему у вас `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "payment")]` и потом на свойстве `[XmlElement(ElementName = "payment")]`? Так нельзя.

Comment: Геннадий П в xml  добавляется только последняя строка из базы данных, а мне нужно все строки добавились